# Getting ouput Class probabilities using Theano CNN for NLP

Tags: python, nlp, theano

I am trying to *use a classifier using MLPDrouput in Theano for classifying tweets into one of K categories*.
Although I am able to get the final class to which a given test tweet belongs to, I am more interested in getting the individual class probabilities for a given tweet. eg. if I have 3 classes, i then want to get the class probability value like [0.4,0.14,0.8] based on which my classifier makes the final outputdecision. Here is my code snippet of my classifier prediction:

```
for conv_layer in conv_layers:
    test_layer0_output = conv_layer.predict(test_layer0_input, test_size)
    test_pred_layers.append(test_layer0_output.flatten(2))
test_layer1_input = T.concatenate(test_pred_layers, 1)
# test_y_pred to store the result of each tweet
test_y_pred = classifier.predict(test_layer1_input)
```

Iterating over **test_y_pred** gives me the final output class but I cannot figure out a way to get prbabilities. Can someone suggest ways of getting the output class probabilities ?

Comment: Usually neural networks give you a score and softmax function converts them into probability values. Then based on the probability values, final class decision is made. If you have the final score for each of the class, just write a softmax function to get the probabilities.

Comment: @Wasi Luckily there was a function in MLPDropout which basically calculates the conditional probabilities for each class P(Y|X). This function is used by the final predict function which returns the argmax over all classes. Based on the thing you commented.